# Where is super pom for maven 3?

Tags: maven, maven-3

For maven 2 it used to be in

M2_HOME/lib/maven-2.2.1-uber.jar:org/apache/maven/project/pom-4.0.0.xml

But 3.0.x does not have a single jar.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

They moved it (without documenting it as usual) to

```
lib/maven-model-builder-3.0.3.jar:org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml
```

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3-LATEST/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html

Comment: I found it on lib/maven-model-builder-3.3.9.jar:org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml.

Comment: For Maven 3.5 : https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.0/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html

Comment: This answer is excellent. Using it as a guide, I renamed the jar in question to ZIP, and used my graphical zip viewer (WinZip) to extract and view the file. Following the path (everything you wrote after .jar, led me straight to it. Learning that JARs were ZIPs in disguise made many things easy.

Comment: in github: https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/maven-model-builder/src/main/resources/org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml

Answer (score 8):

As for `maven 3.5.4` in mac, it's located in

```
$MAVEN_HOME/lib/maven-model-builder-3.5.4.jar!/org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml
```

But you have to `unzip` the `maven-model-builder-3.5.4.jar` first, where the *super pom* hides.

Comment: Nice! How did you find this?

Answer (score 1):

It's documented in Sonatype's Maven reference book, which for some reason doesn't turn up easily in Google results: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/index.html

Comment: -1. The book is incorrect, as anyone inspecting their `${M2_HOME}/lib` will see, that there is no `maven-3.0.3-uber.jar`.  Sometimes, updating a book edition means more than updating the version of the product being described.

Comment: You're right. However, I've found that the book is generally in much better shape than the documentation on the Apache Maven site.

Comment: I have updated the book content about this now. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

For Maven 3.6.1 it's available at https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.1/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html

For any other version just edit the URL.