# How to edit the directory structure in Maven?

Tags: maven

I am using Maven project, when i create the Maven module of jar packaging, maven auto generates directory structue as `src/main/java`, `src/main/resources`, `src/test/java` and `src/test/resources`. Can I edit the above names as per my wish? Can I add new folders to the same parent? Also when i googled, I came to know abt super POM, can anybody suggest how to edit the same with the custom directory structure.  I have configured sonatype maven to my eclipse from the link http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e

Comment: No answer, but the question would be WHY you want to change the default layout in the first place. If possible at all, do not change that default structure - it makes life so much easier :-)

Comment: My project consists of many packages, so thought of dividing the same into different folders with respective names.I dont want to add new module as well.

Comment: Having different packages means several modules (multi-module build) this is against the Maven way. As mentinoned before the default structure make life easier.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you have a good reason to do this, you can rename the folders and indicate to maven what is the edited one by specifying the appropriate properties/sections in `pom.xml` of your project. I suppose m2e will pick up the changes once made to the pom.

The relevant section in your case would be (from the [superpom](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#The_Super_POM))

```
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
```

If you want to add additional source folders or resources (not subfolders), then you can use [build helper maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/).  Again, not sure what m2e will do.

Comment: thanks for the reply, can you pls suggest whr can i find the super pom.

Comment: @user1787641  The modification suggested above should be done in your project pom and not the super-pom.  Leave that as it is.

Comment: As for where is the superpom, refer to [this SO discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797209/where-is-super-pom-for-maven-3)

Comment: These lines belong in the `<build>` section of your project's own `pom.xml`.