# maven testNG approach on directory structure

Tags: java, maven, testing, directory

What would be the best approach:

./src/test/app
./src/main/app/MODULE/test

I am  "somehow" new to java an its testing environment. This given I would like to follow the maven structure as "ant" is too cryptic for a java beginner (I love make).

Then I would start with testNG and not junit.

My application is somehow monolithic, in the sense it is not separable, except a future change from MVC to something a bit more comfortable: a 2 component system to be decided. Which will never be on the  side. They stay as such and within the "monolithic" app.

Then the question: what would be a good starting approach to testing?

- ./src/test/
- ./src/main/app/MODULE/test

Comment: I am sorry, it looks like I am not used anymore to the stackoverflow editor. I will edit the question asap.

Comment: Here I post a generic question, but in principle I would not mind to see the answers in relation to: maven profiles and "git workflow". Pro and cons. I think this is a good generic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any maven project, src/test/ is always more appropriate.

If you add your classes under directory /src/main/app/MODULE/test, somehow you will be able to execute/debug these classes but these classes will get added in the final artifact which you may not wants to happen.

Comment: I accepted the answer, as indeed it should be a mvn standard approach. Which makes indeed the question not relevant. Can we change maven settings? to work for a module based tests?

Comment: You can change the directory structure, but I would suggest not to go for it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333964/how-to-edit-the-directory-structure-in-maven. For module based tests, your packaging structure will work well. We have used the same approach.