# Should I use more recent plugin versions than default?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

Maven by default [uses these versions](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.2/maven-core/default-bindings.html) of plugins such as [clean](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.2/maven-core/lifecycles.html), compile, jar etc. if I don't override them in my `pom.xml`.

Should I be using more recent version of these plugins?  For example, the current version of `maven-compiler-plugin` is 3.6.1 while the default is 2.5.1.  Or, are the default versions reasonable enough that anyone not consciously depending on newer features need worry?

Comment: What exactly is it that you're trying to achieve and is not available with `2.5.1`? Could possibly be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927845/is-there-a-way-to-update-default-bindings-xml-for-maven-on-local ?

Comment: @nullpointer I have no idea what you *can't* achieve in 2.5.1, let alone why I should update to 3.6.1..  "*Are default versions reasonable enough that anyone not depending on newer features need not worry about updating*" is the question.  "Reasonable" can be in terms of stability of build, build performance, or gotchas that may have been fixed in newer versions.

Comment: Best is to define via pluginManagement the newest versions of the plugins. If you have issues with it downgrade versions...It is important to define the versions via pluginManagement to be safe during an Maven update...

Answer (score 1):

The maven way is ["**convention over configuration**"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration), so if you're wondering about not using the default parameters when running a maven build, you should have a specific use case that is not covered by the default version.

Here for example, (according to [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/)) the install plugin is still at version 2.5.2, so that would point to me that using 2.5.1 is not such a bad choice by default.

I think the biggest difference comparing version (I might be wrong) is the upgrading of compatible version as for example this pseudo [release note](http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2015/03/26/apache-maven-compiler-plugin-version-3-dot-3-released/) of the maven compiler.