# Not able to build grails 2.3.7 project since the maven central repository has moved to https

Tags: maven, grails, https, repo

I am not able to build my 2.3.7 grails projects since the maven central repository has moved to https.
I tried the recommandations on this post :  [Requests to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ return a 501 HTTPS Required status and a body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59764749/requests-to-http-repo1-maven-org-maven2-return-a-501-https-required-status-an)

However I'am still having an issue because the maven repo is coded in the framework jars ( grails-aether-2.3.7-sources.jar ) 
The class is **org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.maven.aether.config.RepositoriesConfinguration.groovy**.

```
RemoteRepository mavenCentral(Closure configurer = null) {
    final existing = repositories.find { ArtifactRepository ar -> ar.id == "mavenCentral" }
    if (!existing) {
        final repositoryBuilder = new RemoteRepository.Builder("mavenCentral", "default", "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/")

        configureRepository(repositoryBuilder, configurer)
        final repository = repositoryBuilder.build()
        repositories << repository
        return repository
    }
    else {
        return existing
    }
}
```

This file is readonly.

How can I fix this issue? I cannot migrate the project to a new Grails version for several reasons.
This is the error I got.

> 16:14:10 + /opt/grails-2.3.7/bin/grails --stacktrace clean 16:14:13 |
>   Loading Grails 2.3.7 16:14:17 | Configuring classpath 16:14:20 | Error
>   Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1 (NOTE: Stack trace has been
>   filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.) 16:14:20
>   org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to
>   read artifact descriptor for xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1 16:14:20  at
>   org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:335)
>   16:14:20  at
>   org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
>   16:14:20  at
>   org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:466)
>   16:14:20  at
>   org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:261)
>   16:14:20  at
>   org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:317)
>   16:14:20  at
>   grails.util.BuildSettings.doResolve(BuildSettings.groovy:513) 16:14:20
>     at grails.util.BuildSettings.doResolve(BuildSettings.groovy) 16:14:20
>     at
>   grails.util.BuildSettings$_getDefaultBuildDependencies_closure17.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy:774)
>   16:14:20  at
>   grails.util.BuildSettings$_getDefaultBuildDependencies_closure17.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy)
>   16:14:20  at
>   grails.util.BuildSettings.getDefaultBuildDependencies(BuildSettings.groovy:768)
>   16:14:20  at
>   grails.util.BuildSettings.getBuildDependencies(BuildSettings.groovy:673)
>   16:14:20 Caused by:
>   org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not
>   transfer artifact xalan:serializer:pom:2.7.1 from/to mavenCentral
>   (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ ): HTTPS Required (501) 16:14:20  at
>   org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:460)
>   16:14:20  at
>   org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:262)
>   16:14:20  at
>   org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:239)
>   16:14:20  at
>   org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:320)
>   16:14:20  ... 10 more 16:14:20 Caused by:
>   org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not
>   transfer artifact xalan:serializer:pom:2.7.1 from/to mavenCentral
>   (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ ): HTTPS Required (501) 16:14:20  at
>   org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
>   16:14:20  at
>   org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:342)
>   16:14:20  at
>   org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
>   16:14:20  at
>   org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:649)
>   16:14:20  at
>   org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:247)
>   16:14:20  at
>   org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:536)
>   16:14:20  at
>   org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:437)
>   16:14:20  ... 13 more 16:14:20 Caused by:
>   org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: HTTPS Required (501)
>   16:14:20  at
>   org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.handleStatus(HttpTransporter.java:404)
>   16:14:20  at
>   org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.execute(HttpTransporter.java:298)
>   16:14:20  at
>   org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.implGet(HttpTransporter.java:250)
>   16:14:20  at
>   org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.AbstractTransporter.get(AbstractTransporter.java:59)
>   16:14:20  at
>   org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:418)
>   16:14:20  at
>   org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:337)
>   16:14:20  ... 18 more

Answer (score 18):

You have to comment out mavenCentral() under repositories and add corresponding https url as suggested here : https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334

Example :

```
repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()

        //comment following line to prevent use of default http url
//        mavenCentral()

        //add following https counterparts
        mavenRepo 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/'
        mavenRepo 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/'
        //if by any chance you can't connect to https url use this insecure url
//      mavenRepo 'http://insecure.repo1.maven.org/maven2/'

        mavenRepo 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone'
    }
```

I tried this for grails 2.3.11 and java 1.7.0_242 and it worked for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I was dealing with Grails 2.3.11 and I just added the following repository and changed any other external repository URLs to https:

```
repositories {
        mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
```

Also I had to use Java 8 due to the TLS default being 1.2 in Java 8.  The bummer is Grails 2.3.7 does not support Java 8.