# not able to connect http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/myProject

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/myProject/SalesProj/1.0.0/SalesWebApp-1.0.0.pom
[ERROR] The build could not read 13 projects -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project SalesProj:SalesWebUI:3.1.1 (C:\D_Drive\DN_WorkSpace\SalesClientWeb\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact SalesProject:SalesWebApp:pom:1.0.0 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 10: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 2]
```

attached SalesClientWeb\pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent> <!--line number 5 -->
        <groupId>SalesProject</groupId>
        <artifactId>SalesWebApp</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>SalesWebUI</artifactId>
    <name>SalesWebUI</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
```

Comment: This might be related to the fact, that the major central repos are only reachable via HTTPS since January. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59764749/requests-to-http-repo1-maven-org-maven2-return-a-501-https-required-status-an

Comment: Is the artifact `SalesProject:SalesWebApp:1.0.0`present in your local maven repository ?

Comment: @Benoit yes it is present in my local maven repository.

Comment: See https://blog.sonatype.com/central-repository-moving-to-https  Only https is valid for central...