# Unable to download artifactories using mvn on Cloudera VM

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, cloudera, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am using Cloudera Quickstart VM in my Virtual Box and I noticed that the maven version was outdated. I was unable to download the artifactories using `mvn clean package` due to some HTTPS error which is related to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59764749/requests-to-http-repo1-maven-org-maven2-return-a-501-https-required-status-an) . So I tried fixing that but couldn't so I simply removed the old version and downloaded the latest one.

Now, I am getting a new error which I believe is caused by failing connections to the repository. I am not on any sort of proxy and the proxy section in `settings.xml` is also commented out.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
```

Does Cloudera have any special settings that is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Cloudera in fact no longer provides/supports a quickstart VM for the legacy CDH 5 platform, this can be seen [here](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-14-x/topics/cloudera_quickstart_vm.html) as you get redirected to CDP datacenter.

However be aware that CDH 5 relates to a **very** old distribution. I believe CDH 5 goes end of life this year. Even CDH 6 is not recommended for new clusters, as CDP 7 is already GA for a while. CDP, the [Cloudera Data Platform](https://www.cloudera.com/products/cloudera-data-platform.html) is the successor to both CDH and HDP.

If you want to check out the latest version, there is a trial which should serve for most purposes that you may wanted to use the quickstart. This can be downloaded [here](https://docs.cloudera.com/cdp/latest/release-guide/topics/cdpdc-trial-download-information.html).

---

Full disclosure: I am an employee of Cloudera, the company behind both CDH and CDP.